# How to call database records and the data that also goes with it

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I have some database records for events on certain days and the people listed under the events but they are in two separate tables.

ex.

```
Events  Table

Sport       level          Day
--------------------------------
Soccer      Beginners      Thursday
Handball    Intermediate   Thursday
Football    Advanced       Friday
Racquetball Novice         Friday
```

```
Registration Table

Person        event  
-------------------------
Mike Jordan   Soccer
Mark John     football
Macry Smith   Racquetball
James Reno    Handball
```

What I want to do in a template is display this in a sort of schedule, 
I'm hoping to achieve something along the lines of:

**Thursday**

*Beginners Soccer*

Mike Jordan

*Beginners Handball*

James Reno

**Friday**

*Advanced Football*

Mark John

*Novice Racquetball*
Macry Smith

How can I make this happen? I have gotten as far looping through the events table based on the day and can print the event but dont know how to make the people in those events follow immediately

View

```
Thurs_eve = object.Event.all(day = 'Thursday')
Fri_eve = object.Event.all(day = 'Friday')
```

template

```
<b>Thursday</b>
{% for Thurs in Thurs_eve %}
     {{ Thurs }}
{% endfor %}

<b>Friday</b>
{% for Fri in Fri_eve %}
     {{ Fri }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, the `event` field in `Register` model is a ForeignKey to/from `Events` model.

in that case

```
<b>Friday</b>
{% for event in Fri_eve %}
 {{ event.sport }}
 {{ event.level }}

 People: 
 {% for reg in event.registration_set.all %}
     {{ reg.person }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

it will be then something like:

```
Football Advanced
People:
  Mark John
  Mike Jordan
  ..
```

btw: your ORM should be

```
Event.objects.filter(day = 'Friday')
```

Comment: Yes it was a foreign key , THANK. YOU. SO. MUCH!!